# AD User Group Filtering

Tags: active-directory, admin, active-directory-group

I writing an LDAP query that pulls all users within a permanent group and excluding all users who in the Contractors group. The problem is, some of those contractors need an exception to have some privileges to do things like the permanent groups. The issue is, I can't get the intended users from permanent and exception group and exclude all the users in the contractors' group at the same time. Below is a query that should do so.

I tried to AND both groups (Contractors and Exception_Contractors) together to have only the contractors with exception since the contractors can be in both groups.

```
(&(objectClass=user)
(&(memberOf=CN=Contractors,CN=Users,DC=XYZ,DC=com) 
(memberOf=CN=Exception_Contractors,OU=File Server Groups,OU=GRP,OU=XYZ,DC=INC,DC=com)))
```

The outcome of this LDAP query should include all users in the permanent `(objectClass=user)` group and Exception_Contractors. Please advise further. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find all users, excluding contractors, but including contractors in the exception group.

I think you're looking for:

- The `!` operator, which means "not", and
- The `|` operator, which means "or":

Like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)
  (|(!memberOf=CN=Contractors,CN=Users,DC=XYZ,DC=com) 
  (memberOf=CN=Exception_Contractors,OU=File Server Groups,OU=GRP,OU=XYZ,DC=INC,DC=com)))
```

So that means: all users who are either not in the contractors group or are in the exception contractors group.

On a side note, `objectClass=user` isn't a "group". It just means "all user objects". (as opposed to computer, contact, OU objects, etc.)